# QT4 settext() with array of lineEdits

Tags: c++, arrays, qt4, line, edit

I have an array of lineEdits:

```
QLineEdit *cells[81];
```

But when I try and set the text in them I get a segfault:

```
cells[i]->setText(QString::number(i));
```

How can I access these elements?

Comment: Are you sure you've allocated the line edits?  I'm assuming you haven't, since you didn't show that code and that is the most likely problem.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I can see them on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I set the private array and then redeclared it in local scope. Somehow that didn't make a warning...